# Adding a column to the data that looks for a list of words and adds them if found

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have data that has a column with variable names and a column with the descriptions of variables:

```
library(data.table)
example_dat <- fread("var_nam description
      some_var this_is_som_var_kg
      other_var this_is_meters_for_another_var")
example_dat$description  <- gsub("_", " ", example_dat$description)

example_dat
     var_nam                    description
1:  some_var             this is som var kg
2: other_var this is meters for another var
```

I would like to create a separate column in this data which looks for certain units listed in a vector. I started out as follows:

```
vector_of_units <- c("kg", "meters")
example_dat <- setDT(example_dat)[, unit := ifelse(vector_of_units %in% description, vector_of_units, NA)]
```

But this gives

```
     var_nam                    description unit
1:  some_var             this is som var kg   NA
2: other_var this is meters for another var   NA
```

How should I write this syntax so that it gives the following output?

```
     var_nam                    description unit
1:  some_var             this is som var kg   kg
2: other_var this is meters for another var   meters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `%in%` with `str_detect` and make some arrangement with `paste`,

```
library(tidyverse)
setDT(example_dat)[, unit :=    unlist(lapply(example_dat$description,function(x) 
                    paste0(vector_of_units[str_detect(x,vector_of_units)],
                    collapse = ",")))]
```

gives,

```
#         var_nam                    description   unit
#    1:  some_var             this is som var kg     kg
#    2: other_var this is meters for another var meters
```

Comment: Hi maydin, if you are interested, I just posted a related question, since I needed a bit more flexibility in my actual data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74161558/wrapping-a-string-extract-function-in-an-ifelse-statement